# How to solve this ordinary differential equation from Van Long Dynamic games?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to ask because I did the linear algebra/ode course 2 years ago so I don't remember. It doesn't look like a complicated problem but I can't recall anything.It's from Ngo Van Long's A survey in dynamic games.

Here it is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruzWt.jpg)

It gets you both S(hat) and E(hat). I can do 1.13/1.14, how to proceed further? 
δ, c and ρ are constants.

Comment: E(hat)=δ*S(hat)/2

Comment: What are $E$ and $S$? I see $S^*$ in the second equation. Does this mean that $E$ and $S$ are complex square matrices, and $S^*$ is the adjoint (conjugate transpose)? If not, then what is the $*$ operator?

Comment: @PaulSinclair E and S are functions of t. E(t) and S(t). S* is the rate of change of S, no it is not the adjoint. It's an economics problem so the star is to indicate the optimal value for the variable. They are not matrices.

Comment: Make up your mind: Does $*$ mean "rate of change" or does it mean "optimal value for the variable"? The dot over $E$ and $S$ usually denotes rate of change, so I assume that $*$ is the latter, but in that case, how are you defining "optimal value"?

Comment: S(dot) implies rate of change whereas * implies the optimal value of the rate of change, or the optimal rate of change of variable.

Comment: In case you find a need to ask further questions, please note that you have not yet defined "optimal value". There is no stock general mathematical concept as "optimal value". Any time you see it, it will come with a definition for what the author means by the phrase in that work. But if your question doesn't include that information, it usually shuts off anyone who hasn't independently read the same text from being able to help you, since they don't know what you mean. This is one of the rare exceptions. But please in the future include all relevant information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't matter what you mean by "optimal value for the variable", provided that it is true that when $E$ and $S$ are constant, so is $S^*$.

The two equations in question are 
$$\dot E(t) = cS(t) + (\rho+\delta)(E(t) - A)\tag{1.13}$$
$$\dot {S^*}(t) = 2E(t) - \delta S(t)\tag{1.14}$$

Making the assumption above about $S^*$, there is only one other bit of information you need: $\hat S$ and $\hat E$ are steady-state values of $S$ and $E$. "Steady-state" means unchanging in time, so $\dot E = 0$, and by the assumption, $\dot {S^*} = 0$ as well. Plugging these in, we have 
$$0 = c\hat S + (\rho+\delta)(\hat E - A)$$
$$0 = 2\hat E - \delta \hat S\tag{1.14}$$
Now just solve for $\hat S$ and $\hat E$.

Comment: thank you for the straightforward answer, I was thinking in the wrong direction